# User receive more than 1 notification from nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, notifications, socket.io

This is my first time with nodejs and I have some issues with it. The main problem is that the user receive more than 1 signal from the server. The count is based on the refresh of the page.
Below is my code:

```
var http = require('http');
var server = http.createServer().listen(1332);
var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);
var redis = require('redis');
var sub = redis.createClient();

//Subscribe to the Redis chat channel
sub.subscribe('notification_count');
console.log("Server is running...\nClick on Ctrl+C to exit");

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
    var user_id = socket["handshake"]["query"]["user_id"];
    console.log("user_id", user_id);
    socket.room = user_id;
    socket.join(user_id);

    socket.on('disconnect', function(){
        socket.leave(socket.room);
    });

//Grab message from Redis and send to client
    sub.on('message', function(channel, message){
        io.sockets.in(message).emit('message', message );
    });
});
```

And here is the client side js code:

```
var socket = io.connect('localhost:1332', { query: "user_id={{ request.user.id }}" });
socket.on('connect', function(){
    console.log("connected");
});

socket.on('message', function(message) {
     //something
});
```

Basically on connection from the server I send to the server the user_id. After that I create a new room which name is the same as the user_id. Of course on disconnect the room should be delete. I have noticed that sub.on() is fired more than once, but I cannot figure out why. I will appreciate any help. Thank you in advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are using a handler inside the `connection` event, everytime a client connects it will execute everything inside the `connection` event including your `sub.on`

Place `sub.on` out of the `connection` event and it should stop the double messages